# How i call IntentService from Broadcast Receiver?

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, intentservice

I make an intent service for download data and i want to repeat with broadcast receive and alarm manager.How i call my intent service?I try this but no work....

```
public class MyBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {


    @Override

      public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

          Toast.makeText(context, "Don't panik but your time is up!!!!.",
            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        // Vibrate the mobile phone
        Vibrator vibrator = (Vibrator)   
context.getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE);
        vibrator.vibrate(500);

        intent.setData(Uri.parse("http://www.mysite.net/LEDstate.txt"));
        intent.putExtra("urlpath", "http://www.mysite.net/LEDstate.txt");
        //startService(intent);

        context.startService(new Intent(context, DownloadService.class));

        }
```

public class AlarmActivity extends Activity {

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}

public void startAlert(View view) {

    EditText text = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.time);

    int i = Integer.parseInt(text.getText().toString());

    Intent intent = new Intent(this, MyBroadcastReceiver.class);

    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this.getApplicationContext(), 234324243, intent, 0);

    AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);

    //alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, System.currentTimeMillis()
       // + (i * 1000),pendingIntent);

    alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, System.currentTimeMillis()
                 ,(i*1000),pendingIntent);

   // alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar
    //      .getTimeInMillis(), intervals, pendingIntent);


    Toast.makeText(this, "Alarm set in " + i + " seconds",
        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
  }
```

Comment: What you have defined in your manifest for this class `DownloadService` ?

Comment: Yes manifest is ok.I try to convert vogella tutorial intentservice make replay every x secs.

Comment: did you not try the solution of @Zzokk ? it looks good to me.

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
Intent newIntent = new Intent(context, DownloadService.class)
newIntent.setData(Uri.parse("http://www.mysite.net/LEDstate.txt"));
newIntent.putExtra("urlpath", "http://www.mysite.net/LEDstate.txt");


context.startService(newIntent);
```

Answer (score 1):

In your code you are not passing data, extras to your `Service`. You are adding adding data and extras to an `Intent` object, passing a different `Intent` object to `startService()` method. Use the solution suggested by @Zzokk in the other post, it should work.

Answer (score 0):

When your brodcast getting received, your broadcast activity will called.

at that time you can call any activity as you want.

see below code:

```
 @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        AM_EM_APRIL_2012 = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
                Intent in1 = new Intent(context, AlarmReceiverNotificationForEveryMonth.class);
                in1.putExtra("MyMessage","PAYE payment and employer monthly schedule for March");
                PI_EM_APRIL_2012 = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 1, in1, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
                AM_EM_APRIL_2012.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar_PAYE_20_APRIL_2012.getTimeInMillis(),PI_EM_APRIL_2012);
            }
```

In above code, AlarmReceiverNotificationForEveryMonth.class is the called activity
this is what you have to do if you want to call the activity while the message get broadcast. at that time you can start the respective service as you want.

Hope you got My point.

Comment: You are right.I'm new android development.
How to convert this to work so to me?I would greatly appreciate your help...

Comment: @antkan: i think you should have to refer this: http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidNotifications/article.html

Answer (score 0):

You did not call `startAlert` method in `onCreate` function.